# Is there a choice for ramification points for the covering of smooth algebraic curve over $P^1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a smooth algebraic curve. Suppose there is a branched covering map $\pi:C\to P^1$ where $P^1$ denotes projective line. Say $\pi$ is branched over $a_1,\dots, a_n$ with branching order $\geq 1$.(i.e. Locally, the chart is at least 2-fold covering.) Say $a_2$ has branching order $5$. Denote $\{f_k\}=\{\pi(a_i)\}$.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Is there an automorphism of $C$ s.t. I can make $a_2$ branching order 1? In other words, given $C$, can I twist the map $\pi$ by automorphisms of $C$ and $P^1$ s.t. branching order $a_2$ is changed from $5$ to $1$ but this may produce new branching points? This should look like rewriting the polynomials.

Comment: An automorphism of $\Bbb P^1$ cannot make any difference. Most curves $C$ have very few automorphisms (if any). But, even if you have one, will it help? Say that $\sigma\colon C\to C$ is an automorphism carrying $c$ to $a_2$. If (in suitable charts) $\pi$ looks like $\pi(z)=z^6$, what will $\pi\circ\sigma$ look like near $c$?

Comment: @TedShifrin I guess I did not realize that holomorphic automorphism does not change anything. The branching order is really an invariant attached to a specific covering map $C\to P^1$. I should rephrase my question. Given a smooth algebraic curve, does there exists a covering $P^1$ s.t. every branching point is of order 1?

Comment: For starters, think about your revised question a bit geometrically. Suppose $C\subset\Bbb P^2$. Can you choose a line $\ell\subset\Bbb P^2$ to achieve what you're asking with $\pi\colon C\to\ell$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Since $|\mathcal{l}\cap C|$ is given by degree of $C$ via Bezout, it suffices to ask $\mathcal{l}$ in general position which intersects with $C$ in $deg(C)$ distinct points. So there is open subset $Gr(1,2)$ allowing one such configuration.

Comment: Well, no, how are we projecting onto $\ell$?

Comment: @TedShifrin The standard projection projects to $[x,y,z]\to [x,y]$ away from $[0,0,1]$ point of $CP^2$ but this requires $\mathcal{l}=[x,y,1]$. There is a transformation to make the curve avoiding $[0,0,1]$ but it is not clear whether $\mathcal{l}$ and $C$ avoids $[0,0,1]$ simultaneously. And $\mathcal{l}$ has to be transformed to $[x,y,1]$. Even if that is the case, there is no guarantee $\mathcal{l}$ intersects with $C$ with distinct points. It looks like quite a lot of constraints here. Now I am not sure whether this is even possible.